# botón guardar y continuar en PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando un pequeño formulario donde tengo el botón guardar este me llama a un `if` que tengo en el archivo `guardar.php` pero dentro de este archivo tengo varias variables que detonan `if` para realizar diferentes tareas de otras páginas.

Solo que en la primera llamada al archivo `guardar.php` me pide todas las variables y no las tengo ya que estas variables las registro en otras páginas del proyecto.

**`INICIO_DEL_FOMULARIO.PHP`**

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
           <input type="hidden" name="entradasalida" value="entradasalida" />
     </div>
  </div>
```

**`GUARDAR.PHP`**

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
$_Entrada_salida = stripslashes($_POST["entradasalida"]);
$_Metodo_Que = stripslashes($_POST["metodoque"]);
$_Metodo_Quien = stripslashes($_POST["metodoquien"]);
$_Metodo_Como = stripslashes($_POST["metodocomo"]);
$_Metodo_Cuanto = stripslashes($_POST["metodocuanto"]);
$_Guardar_Riesgo = stripslashes($_POST["addRiesgo"]);
$_Anadir_Riesgo_que = stripslashes($_POST["Anadirriesgo1"]);

//guardar proceso entrada y su salida
if  ($_Entrada_salida == "addRiesgo") 
        {
        $_Proceso = stripslashes($_POST["Proceso"]);
        $_Actividades =  stripslashes ($_POST["Actividad"]);
        $_Entrada =  stripslashes ($_POST["Entrada"]);
        $_Salida =  stripslashes($_POST["Salida"]);
        $query = "INSERT INTO proceso (Nombre_proceso,actividades,entrada, salida)
        VALUES ('$_Proceso', '$_Actividades', '$_Entrada', '$_Salida'); ";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if (!$result) die($conn->error);
        header("Location: ../form_validation.php?var=$_Proceso"); 
        exit; 
        }
// Añadir riesgo en el que del proceso
if  ($_Anadir_Riesgo_que == "Anadirriesgo1") 
        {
        $ID_Proceso = stripslashes($_POST["ID_proceso"]);
        $ID_QUE = stripslashes($_POST["ID_QUE"]);
        $_que = stripslashes($_POST["que"]);
        $_Riesgo = stripslashes($_POST["riesgo_que"]);
        $_criticidad = stripslashes($_POST["Criticidad"]);
        $_Ocurrencia = stripslashes($_POST["Ocurrencia"]);
        $_Reaccion = stripslashes($_POST["Reaccion"]);
        $_Valor = stripslashes($_POST[""]);
        $_Decision = stripslashes($_POST["Decision"]);
        $_Plan_Accion = stripslashes($_POST["Plan_Accion"]);
        $query = "INSERT INTO riesgo_metodo_que (Id_Proceso,Id_Metodo,que,Riesgo, Criticidad, Ocurrencia, Reaccion, Valor, Decision, Plan_Accion)
        VALUES ('$ID_Proceso', '$ID_QUE', '$_que', '$_Riesgo', '$_criticidad', '$_Ocurrencia', '$_Reaccion', '$_Valor', '$_Decision', '$_Plan_Accion'); ";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if (!$result) die($conn->error);
        header("Location: ../form_validation.php?var=$_Proceso"); 
        exit; 
        }
```

Entonces me manda el error:

> Notice: Undefined index: metodoque in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webTMMMX\master\production\PHP\GuardarProceso.php on
>   line 4

Pero pues es lógico por que aun no tengo la variable por que todavía no llego a la parte donde la obtengo.

Answer (score 0):

valida tambien si esta seteada y que este llena, por que puede estar seteada pero vacia asi q te dara problemas. ejemplo

```
if (isset($_POST["metodoque"]) && trim($_POST["metodoque"])){
    $_Metodo_Quien = stripslashes($_POST["metodoque"]);
}
```

no endiento por que usas este metodo de setear variables si no las tienes, incluso si andas validando, igual no existen, te recomiendo q hagas tambien un

```
if(isset($_POST)){
 ///tu codigo 
}
```

asi solo van a crearse esas variables al principio si mandas un POST. o bueno, en realidad no se por que lo haces de esa manera.